# Please can someone explain what the second square bracket notation is doing here?

Tags: javascript, square-bracket

```
function(today) {
    var weekFromToday = new Date(today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
    var dayNames = ["x","y", "z"]; 
    var day = dayNames[weekFromToday.getDay()]; 
}
```

The square brackets in the third var do not refer to an index number, what does the notation mean in this case?

Comment: it is computed property accessor, it evaluates expression and use the result of expression to access value from dayNames

Comment: It *does* refer to an index number, `getDay` returns a number `0-6`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like any other array value getting accessed via index.

Here `weekFromToday.getDay()` returns an integer from 0-6 and if

```
var dayNames = ["x","y", "z"];
```

were

```
var dayNames = ["Sun","Mon", "Tue"...];
```

you would have received the day's name.